# Why $xyz = e^x$ can be seen as the level surface $f(x,y,z) = xyz - e^x$?

Tags: calculus, functions, surfaces

That does not make sense to me. I recognize a level surface from the form $f(x,y,z) = k$. Where is the $k$ there? It looks just like a $3$ variables function to me.

Comment: Take k = 0. Then you have $f(x,y,z)=0$, and this is the same as $xyz=e^x$.

Comment: OK, but why would I be allowed to do that? Seems like you're picking an arbitrary k. The question in case was asking for the directional derivative of `xyz = e^x` on the point (3,1/3,e). I don't understand why the first step would be modifying the original equation to something that is not the same!

Comment: @Dokkat: What is exactly your question? If it is about the level surface, sranthrop gave you a good hint. And if it is about directional derivatives so do that in another question or make an edit below this question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let we have a well-behaved function, say $f(x,y,z)$, so the equation $f(x,y,z)=c$ in whch $c$ is an arbitrary real value defines a surface for each value for $c$. Now, if you assign all possible values $c$ such that the latter equation have any solution, so you'll indeed have a family of surfaces, called *level surfaces* of that $f$. This is exactly what @sranthrop noted. In fact, if we set $c=0$ when we set $f=c$ then we get $xyz=e^x$. The following plots are parts of whole shape of the functions for values $c=1,2,3,4,5$.

[image]

See the layers closer:

[image]

Comment: That makes total sense. What did you use to plot those graphs?

Comment: Great plots, B.S.! +1

Comment: @Dokkat: Thanks. I used Maple 16 for doing that. Thanks Amy.